# Add more fields with campaign in google adwords api

Tags: yii, google-ads-api

Im new to [Google adwords - My client center](http://www.google.com/adwords/myclientcenter/). I want to view and add campaigns with this. I searched for the google adwords api client library and found the following "http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/downloads/list". After that, downloaded the aw_api_php_lib_3.2.2.tar.gz and placed that code in "mysite/protected/" folder. And i have modified configuration in "mysite/protected/adwords/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/auth.ini" file.

I can able to view all the campaigns. Now i want to add campaign with My client center. My code is,

```
Yii::import('application.adwords.*');
                        require_once('examples/v201206/BasicOperations/AddCampaigns.php');
                        $user = new AdWordsUser();
                        $user->LogAll();
                        AddCampaignsExample($user, $campaign_name, $period, $budget, $delmethod, $status, $stdate, $enddate, $impressions, $timeunit, $level);
```

I have passed the appropriate values in the $campaign_name,$period,$budget..etc,. Its working well.

But i want to add all the fields available in Google adwords add campaign like "Type, Location options (advanced), Languages, Ad extensions, Advanced settings, etc.,". How can i add these fields with Google adwords API - Client library. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

@lifeline,
You're using the sample code, not the client library. 
If you want to configure a complete campaign, you need to use the API classes, like the sample code does.

Basically, you need to follow these steps to create objects with the AdWords API:

- Define the service (for example, `CampaignService`);
- Define the object (for example, `Campaign`);
- Set the object properties;
- Add the object in a operations array;
- Call the `mutate` method on service object, passing the operations array (this method will send your data to adwords);
- Get and process the results;

You can see these steps clearly in the [API sample code](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/browse/adx-examples/v201206/BasicOperations/AddCampaigns.php?spec=svn11423d3c5cdd2b83e88e9010cfa33241d325be48&r=11423d3c5cdd2b83e88e9010cfa33241d325be48).
To learn more about the `CampaignService`, `Campaign` object and other things, see the API documentation:

- [Working with objects](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/working-with-objects)
- [CampaignService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201206/CampaignService)
- [Campaign](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201206/CampaignService.Campaign)
- [Location targeting guide](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/location-targeting)

Good luck with your project.